# Keep The User Form Window Active inspite of any background program run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro being run on a worksheet every minute. It copies and pastes data from another worksheet and updates an existing chart.

There is a command button provided which can change the range of x & y series on that chart.
When user clicks on the command button, a userform is shown for user entry of minimum and maximum range.
But as the macro is running every second, userform focus is lost during the macro run and user has to select the user form every time. Its very annoying.

The macro does not select/activate any cell/chart on the worksheet.

How do I stop User form losing it's focus and keep it active in spite of any program running at back end?

Comment: Show us the code that's running when this issue happens.

Comment: As Macro Man said - showing us the code would be useful. From the problem described however, I would suggest wrapping the Macro refresh in an IF - so that it does not run when the userform is live

Comment: If the UserForm is modeless try making it modal: `UserForm.Show True`

Comment: basically the code is opening a csv file and I think that is where it loses focus on User Form

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that runs every second. 'Limits' is the user form name.

```
Sub doitagain()
If Len(Dir(path1 + "\mon")) <> 0 Then
            If Limits.Visible Then
            Limits.rangecb1.SetFocus
            End If

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Interactive = False

            fromcopy = path1 + "\mon"
            tocopy = path + "\mon.csv"
            On Error Resume Next
            FileCopy fromcopy, tocopy
            filepath = path + "\mon.csv"
            Set wtarget = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
            wtarget.Windows(1).Visible = False

            curiteration = m - 2
            i = ii + 1
            n = 1
            Do While wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(i, 2).Value <> curiteration
            i = i + 1
            n = n + 1
                If n > ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 6).Value Then
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Application.Interactive = True
                Workbooks("mon.csv").Close savechanges = False
                GoTo abc
                End If
            Loop
            j = i
            Do While wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(j, 1).Value <> ""
            j = j + 1
            Loop
            j = j - 1
            mi = m
            For k = i To j
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(mi, 1).Value = wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(k, 2).Value
            mi = mi + 1
            Next
            lastcol = 1
            Do While wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(i, lastcol).Value <> ""
            lastcol = lastcol + 1
            Loop
            lastcol = lastcol - 1
            mi = m
            For k = i To j
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(mi, 4).Value = wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(k, lastcol - noofsubsdoagain).Value
            mi = mi + 1
            Next
            mi = m
            For k = i To j
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(mi, 3).Value = wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(k, lastcol - 1 - noofsubsdoagain).Value
            mi = mi + 1
            Next
            mi = m
            For k = i To j
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(mi, 2).Value = wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(k, lastcol - 2 - noofsubsdoagain).Value
            mi = mi + 1
            Next

            For k = 1 To noofsubsdoagain
            mi = m
            Dim ki As Integer
            For ki = i To j
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(mi, 4 + k).Value = wtarget.Worksheets("mon").Cells(ki, lastcol - noofsubsdoagain + k).Value
            mi = mi + 1
            Next
            Next
            Application.Interactive = True
            Set wtarget = Nothing
            Workbooks("mon.csv").Close savechanges = False
            mi = m
            For k = i To (j - 1)
            m = m + 1
            Next
            i = 3
            Do While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
            i = i + 1
            Loop
            If i > 3 Then
            i = i - 1
            End If
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.Interactive = True
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 5).Value = 1 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").TextBox1.Value = i - 2
            Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").TextBox1.Value = i - (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 7).Value - ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 6).Value + 2)
            End If

            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Convergence_Plot!$A$3:$A$" & i
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Convergence_Plot!$B$3:$B$" & i
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Convergence_Plot!$C$3:$C$" & i
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "=Convergence_Plot!$D$3:$D$" & i
            Dim letter As String
            letter = "D"
            For k = 1 To 10
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(3 + k).Values = "=Convergence_Plot!$" & Chr(Asc(letter) + k) & "$3:$" & Chr(Asc(letter) + k) & "$" & i
            Next

            If Limits.Visible Then
            Limits.rangecb1.SetFocus
            End If
End If
abc:
timetorun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
Application.OnTime timetorun, "doitagain", , True
End Sub
```